# Interpreting non standard floating point numbers

Tags: point, floating, representation

I have a document that says the numbers I'm looking at are either "9511" or "8087" floating point format (many errors in the documentation I have - it also says the numbers are "9511 float, eight bytes long, LSB -> MSB". But the 9511 didn't DO doubles...).
They are definitely not IEEE-754, but are four bytes long. 
How can I make the byte string 0x02 0xB2 0x5D 0x07 into "2.787"?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: The byte string 0x02 0xB2 0x5D 0x07 is 4 bytes. Please include 8 bytes.

Comment: That is all there is.  The format is 32 bits.

Comment: Please check again. Didn't the document say "eight bytes long"?

Comment: That's what it says, but like I mentioned, the data format of the AM9511 does not support eight byte floats. I have captured a data stream (RS232), and everything lines up with the floats as four bytes each. so 0x02B25D07 = 2.787, and 0x049765AB = 9.46. I also have the AM9511 data format description, but only as an image - I don't know how to attach, but here is the link:http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/amd/_dataSheets/Am9511_Algorithm_Details.pdf